# method delete 405 error with asp.net web api 2.0 cors . get post put work

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api, cors, asp.net-web-api2

I'm struggling with an ASP.Net WEB API 2.0 problem that CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing).I was installed the ASP.Net.Web.API 2.0 CORS package and enable cors.no webdav.defualt webconfig just like this (see http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)
put,get and post work,delete error with 405 code,what should i do?

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {

        EnableCorsAttribute cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: can you please share your web config, or tell me you have webdav in ?

Comment: no WebDav defualt webconfig

Answer (score 0):

I'm having same issue with PUT method. The solution is Custom CORS policy providers.

The [**EnableCors**] attribute implements the **ICorsPolicyProvider** interface. You can provide your own implementation by creating a class that derives from Attribute and implements **ICorsPolicyProvider**.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class MyCorsPolicyProvider : Attribute, ICorsPolicyProvider 
{
    private CorsPolicy _policy;

    public MyCorsPolicyProvider()
    {
        // Create a CORS policy.
        _policy = new CorsPolicy
        {
            AllowAnyMethod = true,
            AllowAnyHeader = true
        };

        // Add allowed origins.
        _policy.Origins.Add("http://myclient.azurewebsites.net");
        _policy.Origins.Add("http://www.contoso.com");
    }

    public Task<CorsPolicy> GetCorsPolicyAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(_policy);
    }
}
```

Now you can apply the attribute any place that you would put [**EnableCors**].

```
[MyCorsPolicy]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    .. //
```

For example, a custom CORS policy provider could read the settings from a configuration file.

As an alternative to using attributes, you can register an **ICorsPolicyProviderFactory** object that creates **ICorsPolicyProvider** objects.

```
public class CorsPolicyFactory : ICorsPolicyProviderFactory
{
    ICorsPolicyProvider _provider = new MyCorsPolicyProvider();

    public ICorsPolicyProvider GetCorsPolicyProvider(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        return _provider;
    }
}
```

To set the **ICorsPolicyProviderFactory**, call the **SetCorsPolicyProviderFactory** extension method at startup, as follows:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.SetCorsPolicyProviderFactory(new CorsPolicyFactory());
        config.EnableCors();

        // ...
    }
}
```

It should work, But after your deployment if it will not work then Please add the below configuration in your web.config

```
<system.webServer>    
  <modules>    
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />    
  </modules>    
  <handlers>    
    <remove name="WebDAV" /> 
    <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />  
    <add name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" path="*" verb="OPTIONS" modules="ProtocolSupportModule" requireAccess="None" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />   
  </handlers>    
</system.webServer>
```

After deployment, just do **IISRESET** or restart **App pool**.